# MongoDB server crashed, showing the following error

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB instance running in a VMWare VM with Ubuntu Server 12.04. Suddenly the server crashed, and when I try to reinitiate it I get the following error:

```
jonathanong@ubuntu:~/mongodb/solo$ /usr/bin/mongod --fork --port 27027 --dbpath ~/mongodb/solo --logpath ~/mongodb/solo/mongodb.log
Thu Jan 17 00:54:25   Assertion failure getcwd( buffer , 1000 ) src/mongo/db/cmdline.cpp 188
0xaffd31 0xac65cd 0x6878a8 0x55f070 0x565d39 0x7f2b226d176d 0x558149 
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0xaffd31]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j+0xfd) [0xac65cd]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo7CmdLine5storeEiPPcRN5boost15program_options19options_descriptionES6_RNS4_30positional_options_descriptionERNS4_13variables_mapE+0x4a38) [0x6878a8]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0x55f070]
 /usr/bin/mongod(main+0x9) [0x565d39]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed) [0x7f2b226d176d]
 /usr/bin/mongod(__gxx_personality_v0+0x471) [0x558149]
Thu Jan 17 00:54:25 terminate() called, printing stack (if implemented for platform):
0xaffd31 0x55840e 0x7f2b23036846 0x7f2b23036873 0x7f2b2303696e 0xac6776 0x6878a8 0x55f070 0x565d39 0x7f2b226d176d 0x558149 
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0xaffd31]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11myterminateEv+0x3e) [0x55840e]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xb5846) [0x7f2b23036846]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xb5873) [0x7f2b23036873]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xb596e) [0x7f2b2303696e]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j+0x2a6) [0xac6776]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo7CmdLine5storeEiPPcRN5boost15program_options19options_descriptionES6_RNS4_30positional_options_descriptionERNS4_13variables_mapE+0x4a38) [0x6878a8]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0x55f070]
 /usr/bin/mongod(main+0x9) [0x565d39]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed) [0x7f2b226d176d]
 /usr/bin/mongod(__gxx_personality_v0+0x471) [0x558149]
Thu Jan 17 00:54:25 Got signal: 6 (Aborted).

Thu Jan 17 00:54:25 Backtrace:
0xaffd31 0x558bb9 0x7f2b226e64a0 0x7f2b226e6425 0x7f2b226e9b8b 0x558413 0x7f2b23036846 0x7f2b23036873 0x7f2b2303696e 0xac6776 0x6878a8 0x55f070 0x565d39 0x7f2b226d176d 0x558149 
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0xaffd31]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo10abruptQuitEi+0x399) [0x558bb9]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x364a0) [0x7f2b226e64a0]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35) [0x7f2b226e6425]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x17b) [0x7f2b226e9b8b]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11myterminateEv+0x43) [0x558413]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xb5846) [0x7f2b23036846]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xb5873) [0x7f2b23036873]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xb596e) [0x7f2b2303696e]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j+0x2a6) [0xac6776]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo7CmdLine5storeEiPPcRN5boost15program_options19options_descriptionES6_RNS4_30positional_options_descriptionERNS4_13variables_mapE+0x4a38) [0x6878a8]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0x55f070]
 /usr/bin/mongod(main+0x9) [0x565d39]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed) [0x7f2b226d176d]
 /usr/bin/mongod(__gxx_personality_v0+0x471) [0x558149]
```

This is MongoDB 2.2.2 downloaded from mongodb-10gen: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Any ideas?

Edit: So I just created a new VM from scratch and it's perfectly fine. So this isn't a show stopper for me since I plan to use managed hosting. Still, knowing the problem would be nice!

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you're OK, but FYI: this just happened to me. Pretty much the same stack trace. The problem was that as I was restarting mongod, my current directory in this shell happened to be one which I had deleted a little while ago (in another shell). That was why getcwd was failing.

Comment: Same thing for me. :)

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to look at is the provided line of code at the top of the crash:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.2/src/mongo/db/cmdline.cpp#L188

This is basically getting the current working directory.  An odd place to crash - it would suggest a fairly basic problem at the filesystem level - directory not found, or in some other way corrupt.

According to addr2line (see [Parsing Stack Traces](https://wiki.10gen.com/display/DOCS/Parsing+Stack+Traces)) the first relevant line (0x6878a8) points here:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.2/src/mongo/db/cmdline.cpp#L349

That again points to some sort of issue getting to the relevant `mongod` folder (probably /var/lib/mongodb or similar).  This time the relevant error is:

> Cant chdir() while forking server process

Again pointing to a similar root cause in terms of accessing the filesystem/folder that the program is trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I got such error: "SEVERE: terminate() called, printing stack" because of the locate problem. type:

> export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"

would probably fix the problem.

Comment: You may be getting **another** problem. No offense, but have you tried going to the source file mentioned in the stacktrace?