# mongo server does not start on Centos 6.4

Tags: mongodb, centos6.4

I have a mongo server installed and when I try to start it with, always fail.

OS:  CentOS release 6.4 x86_64
Mongo version: 2.4.8

I have other machines working with the same versión and puppetized working fine.

Error:

> /home$>service mongod start 
>   Starting mongod: Thu Dec  5 13:48:47.840
>   terminate() called, printing stack (if implemented for platform):
>   0xde05e1 0x6cf3de 0x291d0a34be6 0x291d0a34c13 0x291d0a34d0e 0xdf7bb1
>   0xdd6a51 0xdd7309 0xdd59a5 0xdd5b09 0x70088c 0x700d2c 0x7010d2
>   0x701111 0x701563 0x6dd695 0x6df459 0x291d0168d1d 0x6cf1c9
>   /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0xde05e1] 
>   /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11myterminateEv+0x3e) [0x6cf3de] 
>   /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(+0xbcbe6) [0x291d0a34be6] 
>   /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(+0xbcc13) [0x291d0a34c13] 
>   /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(+0xbcd0e) [0x291d0a34d0e] 
>   /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5boost11filesystem36detail6statusERKNS0_4pathEPNS_6system10error_codeE+0x231)
>   [0xdf7bb1] 
>   /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11ProcessInfo16checkNumaEnabledEv+0x41)
>   [0xdd6a51] 
>   /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11ProcessInfo10SystemInfo17collectSystemInfoEv+0x3a9)
>   [0xdd7309] 
>   /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11ProcessInfo20initializeSystemInfoEv+0xa5)
>   [0xdd59a5] 
>   /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo36_mongoInitializerFunction_SystemInfoEPNS_18InitializerContextE+0x9)
>   [0xdd5b09] 
>   /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5boost6detail8function17function_invoker1IPFN5mongo6StatusEPNS3_18InitializerContextEES4_S6_E6invokeERNS1_15function_bufferES6_+0xc)
>   [0x70088c] 
>   /usr/bin/mongod(_ZNK5mongo11Initializer7executeERKSt6vectorISsSaISsEERKSt3mapISsSsSt4lessISsESaISt4pairIKSsSsEEE+0x13c)
>   [0x700d2c] 
>   /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo21runGlobalInitializersERKSt6vectorISsSaISsEERKSt3mapISsSsSt4lessISsESaISt4pairIKSsSsEEE+0x32)
>   [0x7010d2] 
>   /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo26runGlobalInitializersOrDieERKSt6vectorISsSaISsEERKSt3mapISsSsSt4lessISsESaISt4pairIKSsSsEEE+0x21)
>   [0x701111] 
>   /usr/bin/mongod(*ZN5mongo26runGlobalInitializersOrDieEiPKPKcS3*+0x3b3)
>   [0x701563]  /usr/bin/mongod() [0x6dd695]  /usr/bin/mongod(main+0x9)
>   [0x6df459]  /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x291d0168d1d] 
>   /usr/bin/mongod(__gxx_personality_v0+0x499) [0x6cf1c9] Thu Dec  5
>   13:48:47.847 Got signal: 6 (Aborted).
>
> Thu Dec  5 13:48:47.853 Backtrace: 0xde05e1 0x6d0559 0x291d017c9a0
>   0x291d017c925 0x291d017e105 0x6cf3e3 0x291d0a34be6 0x291d0a34c13
>   0x291d0a34d0e 0xdf7bb1 0xdd6a51 0xdd7309 0xdd59a5 0xdd5b09 0x70088c
>   0x700d2c 0x7010d2 0x701111 0x701563 0x6dd695
>   /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0xde05e1] 
>   /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo10abruptQuitEi+0x399) [0x6d0559] 
>   /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x329a0) [0x291d017c9a0] 
>   /lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35) [0x291d017c925] 
>   /lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x175) [0x291d017e105] 
>   /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11myterminateEv+0x43) [0x6cf3e3] 
>   /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(+0xbcbe6) [0x291d0a34be6] 
>   /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(+0xbcc13) [0x291d0a34c13] 
>   /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(+0xbcd0e) [0x291d0a34d0e] 
>   /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5boost11filesystem36detail6statusERKNS0_4pathEPNS_6system10error_codeE+0x231)
>   [0xdf7bb1] 
>   /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11ProcessInfo16checkNumaEnabledEv+0x41)
>   [0xdd6a51] 
>   /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11ProcessInfo10SystemInfo17collectSystemInfoEv+0x3a9)
>   [0xdd7309] 
>   /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11ProcessInfo20initializeSystemInfoEv+0xa5)
>   [0xdd59a5] 
>   /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo36_mongoInitializerFunction_SystemInfoEPNS_18InitializerContextE+0x9)
>   [0xdd5b09] 
>   /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5boost6detail8function17function_invoker1IPFN5mongo6StatusEPNS3_18InitializerContextEES4_S6_E6invokeERNS1_15function_bufferES6_+0xc)
>   [0x70088c] 
>   /usr/bin/mongod(_ZNK5mongo11Initializer7executeERKSt6vectorISsSaISsEERKSt3mapISsSsSt4lessISsESaISt4pairIKSsSsEEE+0x13c)
>   [0x700d2c] 
>   /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo21runGlobalInitializersERKSt6vectorISsSaISsEERKSt3mapISsSsSt4lessISsESaISt4pairIKSsSsEEE+0x32)
>   [0x7010d2] 
>   /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo26runGlobalInitializersOrDieERKSt6vectorISsSaISsEERKSt3mapISsSsSt4lessISsESaISt4pairIKSsSsEEE+0x21)
>   [0x701111] 
>   /usr/bin/mongod(*ZN5mongo26runGlobalInitializersOrDieEiPKPKcS3*+0x3b3)
>   [0x701563]  /usr/bin/mongod() [0x6dd695]
>
> ```
>                                                        [FAILED]
> ```

I found similar problems but their fixes don't work.

[MongoDB server crashed, showing the following error](https://serverfault.com/questions/469922/mongodb-server-crashed-showing-the-following-error)

When I try to start with

> /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongo.conf

Mongo starts without problems.

The file /etc/init.d/mongod is the standard file from mongo repos.

dbpath exists and has the right permissions

> /home$>ll mongo
>
> total 81936
>
> drwxr-xr-x 2 mongod mongod     4096 Dec  5 12:54 db
>
> drwxr-xr-x 2 mongod mongod     4096 Dec  5 15:25 journal
>
> -rw------- 1 mongod mongod 67108864 Dec  5 15:25 local.0
>
> -rw------- 1 mongod mongod 16777216 Dec  5 15:25 local.ns
>
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 mongod mongod        4 Dec  5 15:25 mongod.lock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check permissions under `/sys/devices/system`

You may be hitting the issue mentioned here (the new 2.6 release has a fix already checked in for this):

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10623

The most common cause is that `/sys/devices/system/node` is not +rx for the user running the `mongod` process, but you can also hit it for others, not to mention the permissions on the parent folders.

Comment: Right Adam, that was the reason, but it is the first installation of mongo that this happens to me, it could be about the new version.